# How much PM I can send from popular Forum engines

Tags: forum, phpbb, vbulletin, ipb, invision-power-board

As u know there are many engines for forums (IP.Board,  vBulletin, phpBB)

how much PM I can send from one account from this engines?

we are limited or not?

Comment: mainly I am interested in this 3 engine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but in phpBB the number of recipients is set by the board administrator